# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file

Tags: asp.net, sql, csv

I am writing a code to query .CSV file using SQL below is my code which works perfectly fine

```
string fileDirectory = @"C:\TechnicalTest\GskTest\Csv\SampleData.csv";
string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
            + fileDirectory + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";

string sqlCust = "Select Count(order_id), order_id, contact_id from SampleData.csv "
+ "Group by order_id, contact_id "
+ "Order by 1 Desc";

string sqlProd = "Select Count(order_id), product_id from SampleData.csv "
+ "Group by product_id "
+ "Order by 1 Desc";

string sqlOrders = "Select Count(order_id) from SampleData.csv "
+"Order by 1 Desc";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDirectory) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
con.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter daCust = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCust, con);
DataTable dtCust = new DataTable();
daCust.Fill(dtCust);

OleDbDataAdapter daProd = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlProd, con);
DataTable dtProd = new DataTable();
daProd.Fill(dtProd);

OleDbDataAdapter daOrders = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlOrders, con);
DataTable dtOrders = new DataTable();
daOrders.Fill(dtOrders);

con.Close();
```

But when I am trying to call the same code from the function by passing the file path which is retrieved from asp.net file upload control it does not work. Please see the code below.

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fupPath.HasFile)
        {

            string filename = Path.GetFileName(fupPath.FileName);
            String csv_file_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Csv"), filename);
            fupPath.SaveAs(csv_file_path);

            Summery(csv_file_path);

            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
            Response.Write("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);
            //dtSummary(csvData);
        }
    }

    protected void Summery(string fileName)
    {
        //string fileDirectory = @"C:\TechnicalTest\GskTest\Csv\SampleData.csv";

        string fileDirectory = fileName;
        //string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
        //            + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDirectory) + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\'";

        string sqlCust = "Select Count(order_id), order_id, contact_id from SampleData.csv "
        + "Group by order_id, contact_id "
        + "Order by 1 Desc";

        string sqlProd = "Select Count(order_id), product_id from SampleData.csv "
        + "Group by product_id "
        + "Order by 1 Desc";

        string sqlOrders = "Select Count(order_id) from SampleData.csv "
        + "Order by 1 Desc";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDirectory) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
        //OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCSVConnString);
        conn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter daCust = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCust, conn);
        DataTable dtCust = new DataTable();
        daCust.Fill(dtCust);
        daCust.Dispose();

        OleDbDataAdapter daProd = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlProd, conn);
        DataTable dtProd = new DataTable();
        daProd.Fill(dtProd);
        daProd.Dispose();

        OleDbDataAdapter daOrders = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlOrders, conn);
        DataTable dtOrders = new DataTable();
        daOrders.Fill(dtOrders);
        daOrders.Dispose();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a sheet name `SheetName$` instead of file name `SampleData.csv`.

For example,

```
Select Count(order_id), order_id, contact_id from [SheetName$]
```

Normally, here is how you get a file path in ASP.Net, because you do not know the drive letter where your web application is hosted. In addition, you do not have access to a file located outside of web application.

```
var filePath = string.Format("{0}App_Data\\ExportImport\\{1}",
   HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "SampleData.csv");
```

Comment: But it is working fine in page load event. It works fine when I am using string fileDirectory = @"C:\TechnicalTest\GskTest\Csv\SampleData.csv"; But when I am passing the same path through string variable to function it does not work

Comment: My physical path is `@"C:\TechnicalTest\GskTest\Csv\SampleData.csv"` can you help me with this

Comment: `SampleData.csv` should be inside your web application. I think `string.Format("{0}Csv\\{1}", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "SampleData.csv");` You need to set a break point at `Summery(csv_file_path);` and update the file part accordingly.